# Jenkins (w/ Mercurial pulgin) when does build.xml get written? Can updates be issued in Post Build to correct/adjust build.xml?

Tags: mercurial, jenkins, build.xml

Jenkins (w/ Mercurial pulgin) when does build.xml get written?

Can updates be issued in Post Build to correct/adjust build.xml?